# Dependency-injection in real life

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, singleton

I am building a really minimal MVC framework to increase my PHP knowledge and challenge myself. I've come to the point where Classes begin to be dependent on each other to work.
[Dependency injection](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection) seems to be the solution to this and are used by some of the [big frameworks](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/) around.

I've found [Bucket](https://github.com/troelskn/bucket) on Github and have messed around it for a while to understand the basics. **What I can't get my head around however is when it's appropriate to create a Container?**

Making one big container including every possible class that *may be needed* seems nothing but counter-productive to me and I can't imagine that it is good practice. It seems like the recipe for bad performance at least.

In the alternative, which is to make multiple containers, I still don't get how the ever-stinking Singletons are not needed anymore.

Let's say that I would have the following code:

```
$session_container = new bucket_Container();
$session_container->create('Database');
$session_container->create('Database_Sessions');

$log_container = new bucket_Container();
$log_container->create('Database');
$log_container->create('Database_Log');
```

So here we have two containers, or in this case *buckets* for two totally different usages which are mutual by their dependency on the `Database` class.

My logic tells me that the above code will create two independent instances of the `Database`-class, meaning that I still would have to make the `Database`-class a singleton to ensure that concurrent instances of my database connection isn't occurring?

**Is this correct?**

Comment: frequently, you need only 1 container for your application.

Comment: Hi meze - please tell me why I would want that. Isn't the whole purpuse of OOP to make the code modular and thereby to only have the parts needed loaded and in action?

Comment: You need to read more on dependency injection. What you are doing is called service locator pattern, read the article written by Martin fowler about it http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: Hi Luis - I've checked out the link. Thanks. Would you care to tell what especially transforms the above code example from DI to a service locator?

Comment: I try to stay away from singletons. If I want to only use one instance of one class, I only create one instance of it and access it from a DI container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know much about the specific lib, but assuming it lets you use a factory, let the factory return the same instance.

Edit: Ok, this is simply on the Bucket GitHub index page.

```
class MyFactory {
  function new_PDO($container) {
    return new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=addressbook", "root", "secret");
  }
}

$bucket = new bucket_Container(new MyFactory());
$db = $bucket->get('pdo');
```

So in your case you could simply do:

```
class MyFactory {
   private $pdo;
   function new_Database($container) {
     if($this->pdo){
         return $this->pdo;
     }
     return $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=addressbook", "root", "secret");
   }
}
$factory = new MyFactory();

$session_container = new bucket_Container($factory);
$session_container->create('Database_Sessions');

$log_container = new bucket_Container($factory);
$log_container->create('Database_Log');
```

Something like that. Doesn't seem like rocket science.

Edit2: I don't have enough rep points to comment on the question (bit silly), but in response to your "modularity" concern: think of the container as the "glue" of your application. Indeed, if you have a large application, you may want to "glue" inside an isolated part of your application only. That is a valid encapsulation concern. But even then you still need a container that handles injection at the highest level of abstraction. If you just create a separate container for every part of your application, you either end up with unneeded duplication of instances, or you have to apply another level of instance management, which doesn't improve the encapsulation in any way: you're still sharing instances between different parts of your application.

My advice would be to use a single container at the bootstrap level. If you want added encapsulation for specific parts of your application (modules, plugins, whatever), use "child containers". A child container inherits the instances from the parent container, but the parent container knows nothing of the child (as far as he's concerned, he's still a bachelor ;)). Could be that Bucket supports this by default, I know other DI containers do. If not, it's really easy to implement using a Decorator. Imagine something like this:

```
class MyContainerType extends bucket_Container {

    private $_parent;
    private $_subject;

    public function  __construct($factory = null, bucket_Container $parent = null){
        $this->_parent = $parent;
        $this->_subject = new bucket_Container($factory);
    }

    public function get($key){
        $value = $this->_subject->get($key);
        if($value){
            return $value;
        }
        return $this->_parent->get($key);
    }
    /**
     * Override and delegation of all other methods
     */
}
```

Comment: Good answer, even thought it's a better practice to create something called lifetime managers, they would implement logic for perrequest/perthread and so on, so you don't need to write the same code for each "signleton" object (but unfortunately, bucket_Container **doesn't** support it): `$container->create('Database', new RequestLifeTimeManager());`

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your last update. I am reading it through and will get back to you :)

Comment: @meze: _Bucket supports nested scopes for fine-tuned management of lifecycles._ See the **Scopes** headline on https://github.com/troelskn/bucket

Comment: I just read bucket does support child containers. You may want to confirm it does what it supposed to do, but from the looks of it, it should be fine.

Comment: Don't cache the instance in the factory (as per your first example). Bucket will do this in the container. The factory should simply instantiate when asked.

Comment: Yeah I didn't read the question. Child containers are the way to go in this case.

Answer (score 6):

> Making one big container including every possible class that may be needed seems nothing but counter-productive to me and I can't imagine that it is good practice. It seems like the recipe for bad performance at least.

On the contrary. This is exactly what you would do with a di container. The container will only instantiate objects on demand, so there is virtually no overhead to managing all you singleton-ish classes through it.

The biggest problem with di is to distinguish between shared objects (Things you would usually think of as singletons) and transient objects (Objects that have plenty of instances through a normal application flow.). The former are easily managed through di. The latter don't really fit. Having those two "kinds" of objects clearly distinguished may seem like a bit of a hassle, but is really a highly beneficial side effect of using a di container.

Comment: Hi troelskn. Thanks for checking out this question here on SO and your feedback - it made it much clearer for me now!

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about multiple simultaneous connections you can just use mysql_pconnect() or the equivelant for the database you are using. It will check if a connection is already open and use the existing connection if it is.

As far as the container issue, I've seen it done in two ways, which you seem to be aware of both. The first method is to have the framework read your database schema and create classes fore each table. I personally don't like this approach. Symfony is one framework that does this (by using the doctrine ORM).

The more preferred method I've seen is to have a generic container, which basically builds the sql for you given a table, columns and an action. This is the approach taken by codeIgniter:

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);
```

Comment: Hi Regality, thanks for your reply. I am aware of the `mysql_pconnect()` and how Codeigniter does it's DB handling. My question was more generally aimed though, as dependency-injection doesn't seem to be a real replacement to singletons when only one instance can exist